# Algorithm for line subdivision

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry, vector-graphics

I am trying to draw tick marks on an arc of arbitrary number of segments. The arc is a `GeneralPath` object.

I want to draw **n** tick marks along the arc (where n is an input to algorithm). I also need to draw a tick on the beginning and ending of the arc.

Does anyone have any pointers of where I could find such an algorithm?

Comment: Is the line just a horizontal line, or can it be angled? What co-ordinate system are you using? Do the ticks needs to be perpendicular to the line? Or intersecting it etc etc?. ...

Answer (score 2):

Well, a line is a 2D vector. Take it's direction, get the length, divide that by n and then calculate the position of the ticks using the start point, the direction vector and the distance between the start and the tick.

*Edit:*

Some pseudo code as well:

```
double unnormalizedDir.x = end.x - start.x;
double unnormalizedDir.y = end.y - start.y;

double length = sqrt(unnormalizedDir.x * unnormalizedDir.x + unnormalizedDir.y * unnormalizedDir.y );

double dir.x = unnormalizedDir.x / length;
double dir.y = unnormalizedDir.y / length;

double tickLength = length / n;

for( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ ) {
  double tick.x = start.x + dir.x * i * ticklength;
  double tick.y = start.y + dir.y * i * ticklength;    
}
```

This should give you the positions for the ticks on the line. Note that you probably should put the calculations into a class that represents a 2D vector - or better, use an existing geometry library.

**UPDATE**:

Since you're using a `GeneralPath` this approach only applies partially.
I currently can't come up with a clever algorithm but you could always treat the path segments as lines or arcs and iterate over them. The distance between the ticks would then be the path length divided by n and the path length would be the sum of the individual segements' lengths.

Then iterate over the segements and if there is a vertex (start/end point of a segment) between two ticks, then calculate the distance of that vertex to the last tick and start the above algorithm using the distance of that vertex to the next tick.

Something like that:

```
double distToNextTick = pathLength / n;
double distLastTickToNextVertex = ... ; //calculate
while( distToNextTick > distLastTickToNextVertex ) {
   Point2D nextVertex = ... // get the vertex
   distToNextTick -= distLastTickToNextVertex;

   distLastTickToNextVertex = ...;// calculate again
}

if( distToNextTick == 0.0 ) {
  //the tick is exactly on a vertex
}
else {
  //the tick is on the segment starting at the last vertex
  //for straight lines calculate as above
  //for curves use an appropriate algorithm (depending on the type of curve)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You really want to use a [PathIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/PathIterator.html) (via GeneralPath.[getPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/GeneralPath.html#getPathIterator%28java.awt.geom.AffineTransform%29)) to walk along the (slightly flattened) segments that compose your arc. You can make two passes - one to calculate the total length of these segments, and another to actually draw the ticks. In between the two passes, you can calculate the tick number that will be closest to the desired tick-length while still guaranteeing ticks at the beginning and end (or you can allow the starting or ending tick to be too close to the others, and then you only need a single pass).

The actual drawing code would be similar to Thomas', but with segment-jumping as your iterator advances through the flattened path.